flalign's odd behavior with double ampersands (&&)
flalign showcases odd behavior when i try to center text using the double ampersand (&&):

The code with align for reference:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
  \vert
\end{flalign}
\begin{flalign}
  &&\vert&&
\end{flalign}
\begin{flalign*}
  &&\vert&&
\end{flalign*}
\begin{align}
  \vert
\end{align}

\end{document}

As you can see, falign's \vert with double ampersands is shifted to the left compared to the other three environments. I would like to use it in my project. How do I make it properly center text?

Welcome to tex.sx.  If memory serves, flalign with an equation number makes an adjustment for the space required for that number.  That wouldn't be necessary for the numberless (starred) form.

&&|&& is a very weird input, what is the actual intention here, this only centers essentially by accident in any of the environments.

It appears that flalign subtracts off the width of the equation label from the available linewidth, when centering, whereas the other forms do not.
One solution is to add a phantom width to the left-most column of flalign, which accounts for the width of the equation label, by way of \phantom{(\the\numexpr\theequation+1)\mkern9mu}.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\myphantom{\phantom{(\the\numexpr\theequation+1)\mkern9mu}}
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign}
  \vert
\end{flalign}
\begin{flalign}
  \myphantom&&\vert&&
\end{flalign}
\setcounter{equation}{9}%
\begin{flalign}
  \myphantom&&\vert&&
\end{flalign}
\begin{flalign*}
  &&\vert&&
\end{flalign*}
\begin{align}
  \vert
\end{align}
\end{document}


